# How to interpret computation graphs for back propagation?

Tags: python, backpropagation, derivative, calculus

I'm working my way through Chollet's Deep Learning with Python and am stuck on the computation graph application. I've glanced this book before but realized I needed to learn a little more math, so I just finished Practical Mathematics for Data Science, learning some of the elementary basics of linear algebra and calculus. Getting back to Chollet's book, I'm stuck at the computational graphs.

The forward pass makes perfect sense:

x * w + b = 7, with the actual y value of 4, meaning we have a loss of 3. I'm stuck on the backpropgation portion.

At a basic level, I know the backward pass through this simple network uses the chain rule (and partial derivatives) to unravel how the output is impacted by the previous layers, like a nested function. Once we know how W and B and x1 and x2 impact the final output, we can use the learning rate to change these parameters to lower the loss_val, one step at a time (stochastic gradient descent). However, I'm having difficulty understanding how we get 1* 1 * 1 and 1 * 1 * 2 for the partial derivatives.

grad(loss_val, x2) = 1 -> I'm to read this as the gradient of the loss_val in relation to x2. x2 =  7, so I was under the impression it should be 3, not 1, but clearly I'm wrong. I've asked a few people, and they say calculate the partial derivative, but I'm looking for a more concrete explanation so I can follow the math. Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of the loss value with regards to x2 can be found using basic calculus.

```
loss_val = x2 - y_true
# taking derivatives, note that y_true here is considered a constant value, so its derivative is 0.
d(loss_val) / d(x2) = 1 - 0 = 1
```

similarly,

```
x2 = x1 + b
# taking derivatives, again b here is a constant, so its derivative is 0.
d(x2) / d(x1) = 1 + 0 = 1
```

Comment: I still don't understand how we get 1. I know this is basic calculus, but I can't figure out how you get these answers. is d(x2) a constant so it's 0?

Comment: I'm denoting the derivative of x2 with respect to x1 by `d(x2) / d(x1)`. We calculate it by taking the derivatives of both sides of the equation `x2 = x1 + b`. Derivative of x1 wrt. x1 is 1, and b can be considered as a constant value, so derivative of b wrt. x1 is 0.

Comment: pardon me, I'm so bad at math, but why would x1 + b be 1? Isn't x1 6?

Comment: no you're confusing x1 and the derivative of x1 wrt. x1. Those are 2 different terms.

Comment: I still don't get where 1 is coming from. haha. Ugh.

Comment: Do you know how to find `dy/dx` for an equation like `y=x+k`

Comment: would that just be x, becasue k is a constant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250545/discussion-between-sandil-ranasinghe-and-tyrone-slothrop).

Answer (score 1):

```
loss_val = x2 - y_true
```

So,

```
grad(loss_val, x2) = d(loss_val)/d(x2) = d(x2)/d(x2) - d(y_true)/d(x2) = 1 - 0 = 1
```

Similarly,

```
x2 = x1 + b
```

Where x1 & b are independent of each other - changing the value of x1 does not affect the value of b and changing the value of b does not affect the value of x1.

So,

```
grad(x2,x1) = d(x2)/d(x1) = 1 and 
grad(x2,b) = d(x2)/db = 1
```

Finally,

```
x1 = wx
grad(x1,w) = d(x1)/dw = x (for the fwd and bckwrd pass in question, x=2)
```

Comment: but how did you calculate these values?

Comment: @Tyrone_Slothrop - I looked at your chat. It seems like the root of your problem is understanding what derivatives are and how to calculate them. Try looking for an online tutorial about derivatives (e.g.https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-all-old/taking-derivatives-calc). You need to understand derivatives if you're going to understand how nets are trained/optimized.